# How to write exact string inside block instead of executing them? While using << EOF in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, bash4

I have a file configure.sh with following (it creates a test.sh file with configuration, so that i can use that test.sh finally as main configuration task). But it does not work

```
cat > /var/tmp/test.sh << EOF
regex='value=(.*)'
for i in $(cat /var/tmp/test.ini);
do
    if [[ $i =~ $regex ]];
    then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
        #or
        curl -v ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi
done
EOF
```

When the configure.sh is executed it makes the test.sh file completely wrong such as
reged='value(.*)'

```
for i in 
original line1
original line1
original line1
original line1
do
  if [[ =~ ]];
  then 
  fi

done
EOF
```

The EOF block is not writing exactly how i set above. How do you write such string inside EOF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man bash`, section **Here Documents**:

> No  parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word are
>   quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote
>   removal on word, and the lines in the  here-document  are  not expanded.

So write `<< \EOF` instead of `<< EOF`.

Comment: There is a problem i have this curl -v ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} this line need execution.

Answer (score 3):

Change `<< EOF` to `<< 'EOF'` and leave the `EOF` at the end unchanged. Quoting the EOF in this way will stop Bash from executing expansions on the here-document.